# Calling function x from within function y and vice versa in the same program

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion

```
int right(int n)
{
        if(n>0)
        {
            n--;
            top_lim ++;
            cout<<"R";
            right_lim--;
            if(right_lim < size)
            return(right(n-1));
            if(top_lim>0)
-->            return(up(n - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

}
int up(int n)
{
if(n>1)
        {
            n--;
            top_lim --;
            cout<<"U";
            if(right_lim < size)
            return(right(n-1));
            if(top_lim > 0 )
            return(up(n-1));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
}

error: [17] 'up' was not declared in this scope|--> indicates error in code ..
```

Description of problem:

The problem is to find all the possible number of paths in a n*n grid in the portion below the diagonal starting from (0,0) to (n,n)
I basically call the right function first in the main function and then it should print me all paths.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a forward declaration at the top of your code:

```
int up(int);
```

(Make sure to compile that code with full optimizations! :-) )